# Using System Managed Identity from Web App to connect to two different DB? Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: sql, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a .Net App hosted in Azure with System Managed Identity enabled (samplewebapp) and also I have two different DB which the application needs to connect. We have enabled Managed Identity in both the servers and added the users in both DB.

Connection String :

```
     <add name="ProjectConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:xx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=A;" />
    <add name="ProjectConnection1" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=B;" />
```

And we have added the users and roles to both DB using the below query

```
        CREATE USER [samplewebapp] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
        ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [samplewebapp];
        ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [samplewebapp];
        ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [samplewebapp];
        GO
```

We are able to connect to the database A but when we try to connect to database B we get the below error.
[image]

Is this scenario possible or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Which .net version you are using?

Comment: We are using .Net 4.8.1

Answer (score 0):

> Login failed for user ''.

**This typically means that the managed identity has not been added to the database.**

- You might be connecting to the incorrect database or adding the user to the wrong database make sure you add user in SQL database not in master database.
- There could also be a situation where there are two service principals with identical names, and you're using the AppId of the incorrect one for the connection.

```sql
DROP USER [ManagedIdentity];

CREATE USER [ManagedIdentity] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD  MEMBER [ManagedIdentity]; 
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD  MEMBER [ManagedIdentity]; 
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD  MEMBER [ManagedIdentity];
```

- Allow Azure services and resources to access this server” should be set as Yes in Firewalls and virtual networks settings in your Azure SQL DB, in case it was not set earlier during Azure SQL setup.